# How to match the functions?

Tags: c

nrOfMeasurements should be the equivalent to 'how many elements user types in' to make a new function(needed). When I try to compile I get an error for `int measurements_count = getEnter(measurements, LENGTH);` How to fix it?

```
int getEnter(int measurements[COLUMN][LENGTH]){
        int x;
        for(x=0;x<LENGTH;x++){
            printf("Enter number #%d: ", x+1);
            scanf("%d", &measurements[COLUMN][x]);

            if(measurements[COLUMN][x]==0){
                break;
            }
        }
        return x;
    }

void nrOfMeasurements(){
        int measurements_count = getEnter(measurements, LENGTH);

        return;
    }
```

Comment: What error do you get? Apparently it is requiring one parameter, but you pass two.

Comment: @EugeneSh.labo2.c:21:36: error: use of undeclared identifier
      'measurements'
        int measurements_count = getEnter(measurement..

Answer (score 0):

The error is due to the second function:

```
void nrOfMeasurements(){
        int measurements_count = getEnter(measurements, LENGTH);

        return;
    }
```

the variable "measurements" is referenced, however, that specific variable in not defined within the scope of the function.

Hence the error:

```
.labo2.c:21:36: error: use of undeclared identifier 'measurements' int measurements_count = getEnter(measurement..
```

**> How to fix it?**

`measurements` must be defined in a scope where it is available to the function.  For example:

```
void nrOfMeasurements(){
        int measurements[COLUMN][LENGTH];
        int measurements_count = getEnter(measurements, LENGTH);

        return;
    }
```

Or, perhaps `measurements` could be a global variable:

```
int measurements[COLUMN][LENGTH];

void nrOfMeasurements(){
        int measurements_count = getEnter(measurements, LENGTH);

        return;
    }
```

Or, perhaps `measurements` could be a parameter of the function:

```
        void nrOfMeasurements(int measurements[COLUMN][LENGTH]){
        int measurements_count = getEnter(measurements, LENGTH);

        return;
    }
```

Comment: The use of *globals* is not recommended, in fact, their use should be avoided. Your second suggestion of passing the needed information as a parameter is correct. There are very few times when a global is actually needed, and they almost never apply to questions asked on SO.